# How do i refresh the data i retrieve from a service?

Tags: javascript, angular, service

I want to display the list of available rooms in a

list in my home component.

for that I declared rooms variable that i assigned to a subscription to the websocketService.
However whenever i created a new room, it's not added to the list automatically unless i refresh the page.
how do i fix that?

**home.component.ts**

```
   rooms : any;
      constructor(private webSocketService: WebSocketService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder,            private router: Router)
        { }
      ngOnInit(): void { 
        this.rooms = this.webSocketService.getRooms().subscribe(res => {
          console.log(res.body)
         });
       }
```

**webSocketService :**

```
public getRooms() :  Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(`${this.url}/rooms`,{observe: 'response'});
```

**home.html :**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let room of rooms">{{rooms}}</li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 ngOnInit(): void { 
       this.webSocketService.getRooms().subscribe(res => {
          this.rooms = res
         });
       }
```

You need to make the assignment in the class variable inside the subscription where it becomes available

Comment: this doesn't answer my question. This will display the initial rooms when i subscribe to the service, but it won't refresh when the list gets updated.

Comment: When you want to refresh the rooms you have to make another similar call to the API and refresh the rooms again. So somewhere where you want the refresh to happen you must again use `this.webSocketService.getRooms().subscribe(res => {
          this.rooms = res
         });`

Comment: @RandomName you are doing it only once when page startsup on ngOnInit that's why you see the data loading only once. IF you want to refresh on some other place then make this call on that other place as well

Answer (score 0):

Try by converting you variable rooms as observable and just get the reference from the service. In the template You will get a subscription by using Async Pipe.

```
ngOnInit(): void { 
  this.rooms$ = this.webSocketService.getRooms();
}

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let room of rooms$ | async">{{room.someProperty}}</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: this doesn't answer my question. This will display the initial rooms when i subscribe to the service, but it won't refresh when the list gets updated.